# How to Trigger multiple outputchannel on Spring integration ServiceActivator?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, integration

Is it possible to trigger two outputchannel on my Service Activator?

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Constants.CHANNEL_INPUT,
            outputChannel = Constants.CHANNEL_OUTPUT)
    public OutputDto applyValidator(Message<?> message) {
        ...
        return outputDto
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; only one.

If you want to send to multiple consumers, you can make the output channel a `PublishSubscribeChannel` and each consumer will get the message.

Or you can add a `RecipientListRouter` down stream.